# XMLHttp request isn't being processed

Tags: python, ajax, flask, xmlhttprequest

I am attempting to take what a user highlights in order to process it for a query of a database.  While I seem to be able to successfully get what is being highlighted, it seems that passing that information through to the actual database query isn't happening.  There aren't any error messages.  I hope there is a typo somewhere and it is an easy fix, in any scenario an extra set of eyes from a more experienced person would be greatly appreciated.  I am using Python Flask to develop a web app for personal use, here is the code

```
{% block content %}
    <head>
        <style>
        div.sticky {
            position: -webkit-sticky;
            position: sticky;
            top: 0;
            float: right;
            width: 30%;
        }
        </style>
    </head>
    <h2 style="text-align: center;">{{ name }}</h2>
    <div class="sticky" id="sticky_display">
        <button type="button" onclick ="getSelectedText()" style="background: darkblue; color: white;">Query Database</button>
        <form name="testform"> 
            <textarea id="selectedtext">
            </textarea> 
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-8 col-md-8 col-lg-8" style="white-space: pre-line;" id="text_display">
            {{ text }}
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
        function getSelectedText() { 
            var selectedText = ''; 
            if (window.getSelection) { 
                selectedText = window.getSelection(); 
            } 
                // document.getSelection 
            else if (document.getSelection) { 
                selectedText = document.getSelection(); 
            } 
                // document.selection 
            else if (document.selection) { 
                selectedText = document.selection.createRange().text; 
            } else return; 
            function(selectedText) {
                var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
                    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                        document.getElementById('selectedtext').value = this.responseText;
                    }
                xhttp.open("POST", "/query_database', true);
                xhttp.send(selectedText);
            }
        }
    </script>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Not saying this is the issue, but you have mismatched quotes around `/query_database`.

Comment: you right you right.

Comment: Sometimes CORSing your app can solve this:

https://flask-cors.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: Thanks for the input, I ended up just changing around what I wanted to do and it worked out.  Not ideal but what can you do.

Answer (score 0):

By default, POST will send

```
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

which requires that send a URL-encoded form. It appears that you're sending plain text, which would require adding

```
xhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
```

before the `.send()`

Comment: Appreciate the help! Made the changes, the same result however has come about.  I feel like surely there has to be some easy thing I'm missing, or perhaps there is another way to do it.